# MacOS quotation marks turning italic and breaking scripts

Tags: scripting, terminal, keyboard, macos

Whenever I have to write scripts or change my `.zshrc` file for example, it often breaks whenever I type an `"` (quotation mark) -- it gets automatically converted to a italic quotation mark: `“` and it doesn't get recognized by the shell when I run the script. I often have to manually copy/paste a clean quotation mark (`"`) when writing things that are run by the shell.

I am on MacOS Catalina 10.15.6, using `zsh`.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: An apostrophe is `'` or `’`. Your characters are "quotation marks", or simply "quotes".

Comment: What tool to you use to write your scripts? Text-oriented tools (such as TextEdit) will indeed have auto-correction activated. Code-oriented tools (such as Xcode) won't. And of course any tools in a terminal session, including `vi`.

Comment: You will also run into issues with double-dashes (--) getting turned into em-dashes (—), which will break commandline flags. I strongly recommend using a text editor designed for code, rather than prose, when editing scripts. If you want a simple graphical text editor for OS X which is suitable for use when editing code/scripts, popular choices are Atom or Sublime Text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These aren't italic, they're the "typographically correct" open- and close-quotes. But they are pretty useless in a shell

To disable them globally:
System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > uncheck "Use smart quotes and dashes"

To disable them in-application, if the menu is available, deselect "Smart Quotes" in the Edit > Substitutions menu of your application

Comment: I think this misses the root cause which is using a code editor as GlennWillen commented

Comment: My answer is intended to apply to OP's current workflow. If they want to take the time to learn a better text editor, that's great! But "use a different editor" doesn't cover all possible circumstances, like consider a browser-based REPL