# Using sed to replace text with spaces

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I am trying to make a script to change the /etc/pam.d/common-password file to require a minimum password length by changing the line

```
password     [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

to

```
password     [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so obscure sha512 minlen=14
```

To do this I am using the sed command to find and replace the line to add minlen=14 to the end of the line.

The code I was using to try this:

```
sed ‘s/password     [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so obscure sha512/password     [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so obscure sha512 minlen=14/’ /etc/pam.d/common-password
```

doesn't work and returns the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command:` �'` (The unidentified character is part of the error message too, it just won't go into the code section). I believe the error might be caused by the spaces in the text but I was unable to find out if sed requires a different format for spaces.

Thanks for any answers anyone can give

Comment: Are you sure you're using a single quotes? that symbol seems different

Comment: Related: [MacOS quotation marks turning italic and breaking scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610635/macos-quotation-marks-turning-italic-and-breaking-scripts)